# Exporting functions loads the whole file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

I thought by exporting specific functions and use it will only include this function in a compiled file but it doesn't seem so ex:

file1:

```
export function redu1(state = null, action) {
    return state;
}

export function redu2(state = null, action) {
    return state;
}
```

file2:

```
import {redu1} from './file1';
```

What did i see in the compiled file that all the functions are included?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes, I'm using webpack ^3.12.0 and using uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Comment: Then post your webpack.config.js, please

Comment: My guess would be you are not setting 'production' mode

Answer (score 0):

According to [Webpack Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), you should set property `mode` to `production` in your webpack.config.js file to remove dead code from bundle.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  mode: 'production'
};
```

Comment: I don't have mode option and that's mean it will fallback to the default (production):
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/